# Why doesn't Javascript handle divide by zero error in a try catch

Tags: javascript

I have the following simple code that throws an error in a try/catch and the error is handled in the catch.  This works as expected, and the error is logged:

```
try {
    throw new Error('Test Error');
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Caught Error:');
    console.log(err);
}
```

Then I try the next example where the code throws an error rather than me just creating a test Error and throwing it, and the error is suppressed, but not handled in the catch:

```
try {
    let test = 1 / 0;
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Caught Error:');
    console.log(err);
}
```

In this second example, nothing is logged.  Why is this?

Comment: Because 0/1 is well defined? You are dividing 0, not dividing by 0. One is perfectly defined while the other is undetermined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript hasn't that kind of exception, is just returns a special value called `Infinity`.

You can check with `Number.isFinite` function and detect if it was divided on 0.

```js
console.log(Number.isFinite(1 / 0));
console.log(Number.isFinite(1 / 1));
```

Comment: Thank you... this makes sense.